# Error using timeout command - invalid time interval

Tags: bash, timeout

I want to kill a command after waiting for result for 2 seconds. If the command didn't come up with a result (took too long), the command should stop. I have gone through the documents and tested the following command:

```
timeout --kill-after=2 ls /mnt/ftp/;
echo $?;
```

Or

```
timeout -k 2 ls /mnt/ftp/;
echo $?;
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
timeout: invalid time interval ‘ls’
```

Note: The command below stops after timeout period by doesn't kill the process:

```
timeout 2 ls /mnt/ftp/;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation for `timeout` is tricky in a way. If you refer it carefully it says

```
$ timeout --help
Usage: timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
  or:  timeout [OPTION]
Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.
```

Here the option `-k` itself takes a value followed by a value needed for `DURATION` also, so your command should two values back to back when using `-k` as below. The error is thrown because `DURATION` is a mandatory argument to be used.

```
timeout --kill-after=2 2 ls /mnt/ftp/;
```

The first option `--kill-after=2` is part of the `OPTION` flag to the command which takes value `2` and the `DURATION` itself takes a value `2` separately.

```
timeout -k 2 2 ls /mnt/ftp/;
```